# Set a String variable to a Date object in java

Tags: java, datetime

I want to set a hand written `String` as the date for a `Date` object. What I'm trying to say is that I want to do is this:

```
String date= [date string here!!!];
Date mydate = new Date(date);
```

Something like that. The reason I want to do this is because I want my network to have standard Date and Time because since I run them from the same machine the time is being taken from the same clock and it gets different time every time. So I want to get that time and also add 1-2 seconds in the end so I can test my nodes with different times.

Answer (score 8):

Java is strongly typed language. You cannot assign string to Date. However you can (and should) parse string into date. For example you can use `SimpleDateFormat` class like the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = fmt.parse("2013-05-06");
```

Comment: ok with the date is possible but what about the time? do i simply add along? like fmt.parse("2013-05-06 18:52:00");  ?

Comment: @user89910 refer to the JavaDoc of the class: [`java.text.SimpleDateformat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 5):

```
String string = "January 2, 2010";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
System.out.println(date); // Sat Jan 02 00:00:00 BOT 2010
```

updated

```
String string ="2013-04-26 08:34:55.705"
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: how can i put my own time at all those zeros though? that's what i'm looking for

Answer (score 5):

you'll want to use dateformatter

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
Date date = formatter.parse("01/29/02");
```